# split comma separated list with commas embedded in quoted arguments in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have this string:

```
my $string = "2, 16, \"d4,d6\", \"d20,d22\", [0]";
```

and I use split like that:

```
my @arglist = split(/,/, $string);
```

The problem is that originally I never had these commas embedded in quoted string and now I have and I need to update that split regex to handle that case.

**Please**, absolutely don't mention anything other than what I ask. I've searched enough and more than half answers are noise about how complex CSV parsing is etc etc. I didn't write that script that I need fix and all I want is to modify that single line that does the split, so it should be simple regex that does that. There will not be any updates and the text that it splits will be this only:

```
CHROMA_MC_X \width, \align, "d4,d5,d6,d7", "d20,d21,d22,d23"
CHROMA_MC_X \width, \align, "d4,d6", "d20,d22", [0]
CHROMA_MC_X \width, \align, "d4,d6", "d20,d22", [0]
```

**EDIT**
  The answer by Birei was enough to start from. I ended up cooking this regex that perfectly handles my case:

```
my @arglist = $3 =~ m/(?:(?<=")[^"]*(?=(?:\s*"\s*,|\s*"\s*$)))|(?<=,)(?:[^",]*(?=(?:\s*,|\s*$)))|(?<=^)(?:[^",]+(?=(?:\s*,|\s*$)))|(?<=^)(?:[^",]*(?=(?:\s*,)))/g;
```

It looks messy, but it does exactly what I need. It matches quoted lists with comas and returns them *without* the quote marks, there were some issues with empty args that could be present and this regex is messy because it just handles these cases as well and avoids that error with variable length lookbehind that isn't implemented in perl regex.

What I don't get: What's the reason for all these downvotes, am I under attack of some perl gurus who think I don't know what I need and what I ask for?! I have tool that does some asm preprocessing and all I needed is to handle a few cases. THAT'S IT. Thanks for help.

Comment: Your data has changed, so you have to modify the program to handle the new requirements.  You cannot do it with a `split` regex.  You might be able to handle it with a limited case regex if the number of fields is known and fixed. It's easier if certain fields are always quote-enclosed and other fields are never quote enclosed. If some fields can sometimes be quote-enclosed and sometimes not, then the regexes get harder. If the quote-enclosed fields never contain embedded quotes, you can get by with simpler regexes than if they can contain embedded quotes; ditto if the data is never malformed.

Comment: Unfortunately, your first example has 5 fields; the first 'CHROMA_MC_X' example has 4 fields; the last two also have 5 fields.  You really need to use [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV). And one of the many benefits of doing that is that it will provide you with a measure of future-proofing.  Any regex-based solution will be fragile; using `Text::CSV` eliminates most of that fragility.

Comment: Your data isn't orthodox CSV, either.  CSV doesn't recognize/allow spaces after the comma that are not part of the field.  In particular, the quotes should come immediately after the comma in a standard CSV format:  `my $string = q{2,16,"d4,d6","d20,d22",[0]};`

Comment: I specified all input data with quoted commas that ever fed to this regex. The other constraint is that there could be empty fields, e.g. two commas with nothing between them, and regex that matches quoted token preferably should drop the quotes. Anyways, @Birei has given alternative that works for me, all I did is to strip the matching quotes from matching quoted args

Comment: Just to clarify. This is arm assembly code macro invocation. Apple severely broke regular gnu assembler (they took ancient version and still have that old gas) and people had to write predecessor in perl that handles some sort of gas macro capabilities. It just happened that some of my args have embedded commas. So, as long as I'm able to assemble it right now I'm good to go to the next toll gate and I don't really care if anybody else will need to mess with it in the future. 4 or 5 args is the macro thing in gas: you can freely omit some of them

Comment: come on, folks, surely someone will actually provide a split regex for this (yes, it's possible)

Comment: there is an accepted answer already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = "2, 16, \"d4,d6\", \"d20,d22\", [0]";
my @arglist = $string =~ m/("[^"]+"|[^,]+)(?:,\s*)?/g;
printf qq[%s\n], join qq[\n], @arglist;
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

With following result:

```
2
16
"d4,d6"
"d20,d22"
[0]
```

Comment: this works `my @arglist = $3 =~ m/("[^"]+"|[^,]+)(?:,\s*)?/g;` Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You say that you don't want to do anything other than `split`, but [Text::CSV_XS](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV_XS) handles this just fine. Maybe you don't like that answer for whatever emotional reasons you've attached to the problem, but someone else might appreciate it. Remember, this isn't a site to help you with your problem, it's a site to help everyone.

```
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new(
    {
    allow_whitespace => 1,
    }
    ) or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV_XS->error_diag;

$" = "\n";
while( my $row = $csv->getline( $filehandle ) ) {
    say "@$row\n";
    }
```

Comment: not emotional, it's just because I expected these type of answers, but this isn't needed for my particular case. So, I stated that clearly. In short, I need to process three different strings that contain that data. I could even compare input for these three types of input (see original question, all of them are listed there) that contain quoted commas and return hard-coded arrays.

Comment: actually, I'm not sure if split is the same as regex match. I ended up using regex match. Most likely, it's impossible to do that with split provided that I needed to add some extra functionality on top, and I was able to do that all in one regex match. I updated original question with my final solution.

Answer (score 5):

[Data::Record](http://p3rl.org/Data::Record)

> Sometimes we need data split into records and a simple split on the input record separator ($/) or some other value fails because the values we're splitting on may allowed in other parts of the data. Perhaps they're quoted. Perhaps they're embedded in other data which should not be split up.
>
> This module allows you to specify what you wish to split the data on, but also speficy an "unless" regular expression. If the text in question matches the "unless" regex, it will not be split there. This allows us to do things like split on newlines unless newlines are embedded in quotes.

Comment: It seemed like a good solution, but I couldn't install Data::Record on the dev box to try it. I tried it afterwards, but I would still need to do manual processing to strip quotes from quoted lists. I got a good start in one of the answers and I ended up writing my own regex that does the job in one line. Thanks for help.